# Unknown columns for grid

Tags: shieldui

We have a large document archive. It is built similarly to how a Cassandra Database would store items having column names and column values stored for each item.

This can lead to having way to many columns. This is how it looked on our old system using WebParts. 
[image]
It's not so much that the user NEEDS to see every column, it really depends on which documents the user has in their archive. Look at this as a sort of tuple table. They should see all the columns required based on the document in the row that is why all those columns were shown in the original design . We present a list of documents that are in their archive and the first column has a link to open the document. The sorting should be able to be done on any column. We do have a lot of different document types.

Now, in one section of our app, we are currently using a Bootstrap Accordian and loading each "row" with just the columns applicable for that row. This is on the front page and we only show 5 of their documents here. The full documents list is described below.
[image]
But, this configuration negates sorting or filtering of the data.

For the full document list, we use FooTable, http://themergency.com/footable/, it allows sorting and column "hiding".
[image]
The "+" in the first column opens up a detail showing all the columns. The "Open" is a link to open the document.

The data is sent from our ERP to a ASP.Net WPF web service and formatted like this:

```
Archive object
    public List<string> Header
        Contains the columns for the rows sent 
    public List<List<string>> Rows
        Contains data for rows sent
```

It was done like this because we never know what columns are going to be in the document list for a particular user, for a particular "group" of their documents.

I programatically format the data to pass to the FooTable at this time and will be making modifications in the near future to get the data directly from the web service in the correct format.

I would like to use the ShieldUI grid to do this but am not sure how I can present the data to the user if I have to put so many columns in there. Any ideas?

Since this is also mobile friendly based on the Bootstrap layout this table will have to be, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next release of the ShieldUI grid component will contain the column hiding feature, which I believe will solve the issue, which you mentioned.

Comment: But will it have the capability to assign and show/hide columns dynamically

Comment: Can the templates for details, demo here: https://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-rows/detail-templates, be created on-the-fly so that I may be able to show certain columns in the grid but then show all the rest of the columns in the detail, no matter what columns are avail?